# how to GET responses when data post to URL

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, post, get

I know about how to post data (UITextField values) to JSON url using POST.But now i tried post Data using GET method to server.I have 10 textFields.I tried like this way

```
NSString *post1 =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"?&dealImage=%@&dealcatid=%@&DeaTitle=%@&DealDesc=%@&price=%@&cityId=%@&StartDate=%@&EndDate=%@&FromTime=%@&ToTime=%@",
     strEncoded, string1 ,pTitle.text ,Description.text ,pPrice.text,string2,beginDate,endDate,beginTime,endTime];



     NSData *postData = [post1 dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];


     NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[postData length]];


    NSLog(@"array array %@",postLength);

     NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] ;


     [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://192.168.3.125:8090/SaveDollar/rest/deals/add"]]];


     NSLog(@"getData%@",request);

     [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];



     [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];


     [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Current-Type"];



     [request setHTTPBody:postData];

     NSLog(@"getData%@",request);

     con3 = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

     if(con3)
     {     
     webData3=[NSMutableData data];
     NSLog(@"Connection successfull");
     NSLog(@"GOOD Day My data %@",webData3);
     }
     else
     {
     NSLog(@"connection could not be made");
     }



- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {

   if (connection ==con3)
    {
          [webData3 setLength:0];

    }

}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {

    if (connection ==con3)
    {
    [webData3 appendData:data];

    }
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    if (connection ==con3) {
        NSLog(@"SOMETHING WENT WRONG WITH URL3");

    }

}
   - (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{
   if (connection==con3)
    {  NSLog(@"Succeeded! Received %d bytes of data",[webData3 length]);
        NSLog(@"Data is %@",webData3);
         NSString *responseText = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:webData3 encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"Response: %@", responseText);//holds textfield entered value
         NSString *newLineStr = @"\n";
        responseText = [responseText stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<br />" withString:newLineStr];
        NSLog(@"ResponesText %@",responseText);
    }
 }
```

When after submit console will be show this message"SOMETHING WENT WRONG WITH URL3"
I know posting but now I need post Data and the Get Response also.So I used GET Method but i am not getting response.So Please give me any idea. And then Please tell me what wrong in my code.

Comment: use POST Method Man, and also check ur String is match with server string

Answer (score -1):

you should collect response data like this:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response 
{
    _responseData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data 
{
    [_responseData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error 
{
    // connection fail
}
```

where data is `NSMutableData *_responseData;`

Comment: thank for Reply i placed like here if(con3)
     {     
     webData3=[NSMutableData data];
     NSLog(@"Connection successfull");
     NSLog(@"GOOD Day My data %@",webData3);
     }

Comment: i place like here - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    
   if (connection ==con3)
    {
          [webData3 setLength:0];
        
    }
    
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    
    if (connection ==con3)
    {
    [webData3 appendData:data];
    
    }
}

Comment: the answer is not actual, because question has been changed

Answer (score -1):

Use the callback function

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
```

If the call is failing the error variable will help you see what is going wrong so you can figure it out yourself.

One thing which might help too is to set your request's content-type field to application/json.

Comment: thanks for reply i add that method also -(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    if (connection ==con3) {
        NSLog(@"SOMETHING WENT WRONG WITH URL3");
        
    }
  
} after submit button  console will be show "SOMETHING WENT WRONG WITH URL3" message

Comment: In method's implementation change the ns log to 

    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error.description");

There is no point just printing that it failed, try and look at actually why it failed by looking at the NSError. It might be able to tell you what went wrong. Alternatively, run the code in debug mode and look at the variable that way.

Comment: thanks when place line NSLog(@"Error: %@", error.description");                      it's showing like this Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=303 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error 303.)" UserInfo=0x13786c60 {NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://192.168.3.125:8090/SaveDollar/rest/deals/add, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://192.168.3.125:8090/SaveDollar/rest/deals/add}